# Selenium unable to send keys on inputbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to send_keys()` to a specific input box on a website and I get an error that says that **the element is not interactable**, as seen below (including code):

```py
def createEmails():
    url = "myurl"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}[!] Waiting for website to load fully.")
    time.sleep(5)

    username, password = generateData()

    usernameField = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
    usernameField.send_keys(username)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukap\Desktop\ASDF\creatorasdf.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lukap\Desktop\ASDF\creatorasdf.py", line 41, in main
    chosenOption(optionInput)
  File "C:\Users\lukap\Desktop\ASDF\creatorasdf.py", line 47, in chosenOption
    createEmails()
  File "C:\Users\lukap\Desktop\ASDF\creatorasdf.py", line 70, in createEmails
    usernameField.send_keys(username)
  File "C:\Users\lukap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\lukap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\lukap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\lukap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134)
```

I am not sure what do to, had already found some answer and nothing helped fix my issue.

I'm trying to make an account on a service called *Proton.me*

Comment: I tried using implicitily_wait and some guy mentioned I should do it w/ ActionChains but it didn't work

Comment: I don't find _usernameField_ field on https://proton.me/ landing page neither any code attempts.

Comment: Well the register page is on https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=free&billing=12&ref=prctbl&minimumCycle=12&currency=EUR&product=mail&language=en and also the usernameField is just the variable in my code for an inputbox with id email.

Answer (score 0):

you have an `iframe` tag in the html of the website you mentioned above that you have to switch to it first then you can find the email element
, you can find the iframe using its xpath [image]

```
frame_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[2]/form/iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_element)

usernameField = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
usernameField.send_keys('username')
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Username* field is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=free&billing=12&ref=prctbl&minimumCycle=12&currency=EUR&product=mail&language=en")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Username']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys("komko")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=free&billing=12&ref=prctbl&minimumCycle=12&currency=EUR&product=mail&language=en")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Username']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys("komko")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: proton]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)